# How to show first post from category in Jekyll with Liquid

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I can't find a solution. I have three categories: tuts, news, code.

The newest post is categorized in *tuts*. But I want to show the last and newest post in *news*. I tried the following, but obviously it doesn't show anything, because if I limit the loop to the first item, which is the *tuts* item, the loop stops.

```
{% for post in site.posts limit:1 %}
    {% if post.categories contains 'news' %}
        <a href="{{ site.url }}/news/">NEWS</a></strong> › <a href="{{ site.url }}{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**How do I show the first posting from a special category? Can I loop directly through a chosen category like this? If yes, what is the correct syntax?**

```
{% for post in site.posts.categories.news limit:1 %}
        <a href="{{ site.url }}/news/">NEWS</a></strong> › <a href="{{ site.url }}{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to directly loop all posts for a certain category or tag.

It's just:

```
  {% for post in site.categories['news'] limit:1 %}
    <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
  {% endfor %}
```

It's the same for tags, you just have to replace `site.categories['news']` by `site.tags['news']`.

Comment: Is there any way to do it efficiently for multiple tags?